# Table left border too thick, and background colour not filling within border radius

Tags: html, css

I have a table that isn't being styled as I expect.

The left side border is too thick, and the background colour on the right doesn't quite fit perfectly within the border radius:
[image: image showing the incorrect styling]

I'm not sure why this, any ideas? I've included my code with an MWE.

```css
table {
    font-family: Avenir, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: #ffffff;
    border-collapse: collapse;
    border-width: 2px;
    border-color: #dedede;
    border-style: solid;
    color: #000000;
    border-radius: 10px;
    border-collapse: separate !important;
    border-spacing: 0;
  }

  table td, table th {
    border-right: solid 1px #dedede;
    border-left: solid 1px #dedede;
    padding: 10px;
  }

  table thead {
    font-size: 1.6em;
  }

  table th:last-child {
    border-right: 0px;
    border-top-right-radius: 10px;
    background-color: #edf2f4;
  }

  table td:last-child {
    border-right: 0px;
    background-color: #edf2f4;
  }

  .last-td {
    border-right: 0px;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 10px;
    background-color: #edf2f4;
  }
```

```html
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th> alpha </th>
      <th> beta </th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>

    <tr>
      <td> lorem </td>
      <td> lorem </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my solution, everything looks correct.

```css
table {
  font-family: Avenir, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #ffffff;
  border-collapse: separate;
  border-spacing: 0;
}
table tr th,
table tr td {
  border-right: 2px solid #dedede;
  border-bottom: 2px solid #dedede;
  padding: 10px;
}

table tr th:first-child,
table tr td:first-child {
  border-left: 2px solid #dedede;
}
table tr th:first-child,
table tr td:first-child {
  border-left: 2px solid #dedede;
}
table tr th {
  background: #eee;
  text-align: left;
  border-top: solid 2px #dedede;
}

table td:last-child {
  background-color: #edf2f4;
}

/* top-left border-radius */
table tr:first-child th:first-child {
  border-top-left-radius: 10px;
}

/* top-right border-radius */
table tr:first-child th:last-child {
  border-top-right-radius: 10px;
}

/* bottom-left border-radius */
table tr:last-child td:first-child {
  border-bottom-left-radius: 10px;
}

/* bottom-right border-radius */
table tr:last-child td:last-child {
  border-bottom-right-radius: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div>
    <table>
        <tr>
            <th>item1</th>
            <th>item2</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>item1</td>
            <td>item2</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>item1</td>
            <td>item2</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>item1</td>
            <td>item2</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

The border at right was thinner than left because of this line - `border-right: 0px;`. The last `<td>` and `<tr>`'s right border had 0 px while the first ones had 1 px on their left which resulted in border being thicker. The below code will solve that problem.

```css
table {
  font-family: Avenir, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #ffffff;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  border-width: 2px;
  border-color: #dedede;
  border-style: solid;
  color: #000000;
  border-radius: 10px;
  border-collapse: separate !important;
  border-spacing: 0;
}

table td,
table th {
  border-right: solid 1px #dedede;
  border-left: solid 1px #dedede;
  padding: 10px;
}

table thead {
  font-size: 1.6em;
}

table th:last-child {
  border-top-right-radius: 10px;
  background-color: #edf2f4;
}

table td:last-child {
  background-color: #edf2f4;
}

.last-td {
  border-right: 0px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 10px;
  background-color: #edf2f4;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th> alpha </th>
      <th> beta </th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>

    <tr>
      <td> lorem </td>
      <td> lorem </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Thank you, @Archit Gargi! That's helped to solve the border issue. The background colour doesn't quite fit inside the border though (it seems to stop 1px before reaching the border, if that makes sense) -- any ideas why that might be?

Comment: I don't think this answer the question that is asked. Still the borders are not proper.

Comment: @SumitSharma Well I answered only a part of the question…

Answer (score 1):

You have used `border` twice in your code for `th` and `td`

```css
table {
    font-family: Avenir, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: #ffffff;
    border-collapse: collapse;
    border-width: 2px;
    border-color: #dedede;
    border-style: solid;
    color: #000000;
    border-radius: 10px;
    border-collapse: separate !important;
    border-spacing: 0;
  }

  
  table td, table th {
    border-right: solid 1px #dedede;
    padding: 10px;
  }

  table thead {
    font-size: 1.6em;
  }

  table th:last-child {
    border-right: 0px;
    border-top-right-radius: 8px;
    background-color: #edf2f4;
  }

  table td:last-child {
    border-right: 0px;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 8px;
    background-color: #edf2f4;
  }

  .last-td {
    border-right: 0px;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 10px;
    background-color: #edf2f4;
  }
```

```html
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th> alpha </th>
      <th> beta </th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>

    <tr>
      <td> lorem </td>
      <td> lorem </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```